# Jetpack Compose: most performant way to show a grid of many icons to select from

Tags: performance, android-jetpack-compose

I'm allowing users to select an icon from the full list of FontAwesome icons (using a `List<ImageVector>`). I'm going to open a dialog, and show the icons as IconButtons arranged in the list. There are ~1600 icons.

I implemented it using a `LazyVerticalGrid`, with a fixed number of columns. It works, but there's some lag loading the icons, and lag when scrolling the icons.

I'm converting this from a React Native project where I did the same thing (with a larger set of icons, actually) and scrolling that was pretty snappy, so I'm assuming it's possible to do performantly on native. Perhaps `ImageVectors` are heavier than the SVGs I was using in React Native?

I'm planning to provide a search box in the dialog where users can filter the list down by doing a fuzzy search on icon names, so the grid will change over time.

What sort of patterns should I be looking at here? Is `LazyVerticalGrid` the way to go, or should I be using a different approach entirely?

Comment: Did you try it in a release build?

Comment: @Subfly I have, yes, and it definitely helped. Still laggy, especially the first 2 times I scroll the grid. Is it possible to eagerly compose out of view items in the `LazyVerticalGrid`, perhaps on some lower priority thread or during downtime of the main thread?

Comment: If I use a normal Column, for example, it lags while loading but is then really fast. I'd love a middle ground where it does a lazy init, but loads everything over time before scrolling so I can scroll quickly. Or will that use up too much RAM?

Comment: Are you loading the 1600 vector items at once? Do you use a view model to get these images? There can be many reasons for the lag, but the sentence "especially the first 2 times" makes me wonder if you are loading that 1600 icons at once. or another thing maybe, as <yes> vector images are heavier, you can use glide library to load the images async.

Comment: To display many icons without performance issues, try using a LazyLoad component or RecyclerView. These can reduce the amount of data loaded and improve scrolling. Experiment with different approaches to find the best solution.

Comment: ¿How are you loading your icons? ¿What's the size of the inflated bitmaps?

Comment: The problem probably lies in loading images. You mentioned SVGs. Are you loading SVGs in runtime? There's no native system support for SVGs in Android, so any runtime SVG parsing is a memory-heavy process.

Comment: @BartekLipinski -- Won't this help? https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists#content-type

Comment: Looked it up. Seems SVG is natively supported in Android since Android 5.0  (API Level 21). https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio

Comment: But not in runtime. You can compile SVGs to vector assets which **are** supported natively. SVGs parsed in runtime are not supported out of the box.

Comment: @BartekLipinski -- Ok, makes sense. And would the usage of vector assets and contentType, besides the usage of the Paging Library, help in the given use case or am I missing something?

Comment: Yup. `Lazy<Composable>` + vector assets (the "lazy" component is the most important thing). It's all a bit of a wishy-washy advice because I don't really know details. I suspect you won't get much benefit from `contentType` because you probably don't have many types in the scrollable element, do you? Just the one that displays assets? Paging potentially, but it's mostly useful for asynchronously loaded content. And I assume all your assets are static.

Comment: @BartekLipinski -- Thank you. I updated my answer correspondingly, taking into consideration and referring to your and Subfly's comments. I would appreciate if you could take a minute to review https://stackoverflow.com/a/74796167/19980636 in case something is still missing.

Answer (score 1):

#### On Laziness

For an overview of use cases and appliable patterns you might be interested in the Android Dev Docs' page on [Lists and Grids](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists), încluding the topics [Large data-sets (Paging)](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists#large-datasets) and the [Tips on using Lazy layout](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists#lazy-layouts-tips).

This might wake your interest on the [Android Jetpack Paging Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-overview) `androidx.paging`, which is designed for loading and displaying pages from large datasets, basically uniting the concepts of Laziness and Caching.

Currently you're only using Laziness. As [Bartek Lipinski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1993204/bartek-lipinski) commented, that should usually be fine when the graphics to display are static. However, when they have to be loaded asynchronously, Paging will probably improve your performance.

*Some Rules of Thumb*

| Scrolling | Pattern |
| --- | --- |
| No | `Column` or `Row` will be enough |
| Some | `Column` or `Row` with modifiers `verticalScroll` and `horizontalScroll` |
| More, static content | `LazyColumn` or `LazyRow`, resp. for gridding `LazyVerticalGrid` or `LazyHorizontalGrid` |
| More to mass, dynamic content | `LazyColumn` or one of its relatives with `LazyPagingItems`, so using the **Paging Library** `androidx.paging` |

Also, as the docs say, [consider adding contentType](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists#content-type)
. However, as [Bartek Lipinski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1993204/bartek-lipinski) remarked, one usually benefits of `contentType` when there are scrollable elements of various types -- not only SVGs as maybe in your case. Still, giving hints to the system doesn't hurt, at least.

#### On Vector Graphics

As discussed in the comments, esp. by [Subfly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10840292/subfly) and [Bartek Lipinski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1993204/bartek-lipinski), though Laziness should be the main thing here, another bottleneck could be the loading of vector graphics during runtime.

If the graphics used are of static nature, then consider the usage of [vector graphic assets](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio). Those are supported for SVG and PSD since Android 5.0 (API level 21). Take also a look on the [recommendations](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio#when) and some aspects of [support and restrictions on SVG](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio#svg-support).

#### Summary

The basic formula is `Laziness + Vector Assets` with focus on the first. One might spice that with contentType and Paging.